# mod_status doesn't show originator IP

Tags: apache-2.2

When using mod_status to resolve Apache 2 performance issues, I notice one
of my Vhosts is getting heavy traffic, but under the "**`Client`**" column instead
of seeing the IP address of the remote machine, mod_status provides only "::1".

What does that mean? is it possible to camouflage a remote machine IP address in
this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is localhost in IPv6 notation.